# can the return value of "__float_as_int" be used to compare float in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

`__float_as_int` reinterprets `float` as an `int`, but I don't know the reinterpreted `int` can be used to compare the `float` value

```
__float_as_int(floatA) > __float_as_int(floatB)  =>  floatA > floatB
```

and

```
floatA > floatB  =>  __float_as_int(floatA) > __float_as_int(floatB)
```

is this correct?

Comment: @njuffa commented on this topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563307/how-to-prevent-ftz-for-a-single-line-in-cuda)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly replace 'float' comparison with integer comparison, but only for numbers of like sign. This will work correctly for operands that are zero, denormal, normal, or infinity, but not if one or both operands are NaN. NaNs are unordered by definition, but the integer comparison imposes order on those encodings. You will also not get any flush-to-zero behavior for denormals.

If both operands are positive, and you want to compare the `float` operands with `rel-op>`, where `<rel-op>`is one of `==, !=, <, >, <=, >=` simply use

`if (__float_as_int(a) <rel-op> __float_as_int(b))`

since the bit patterns are going to range from `0x00000000` for positive zero, over `0x00000001` for smallest denormal, `0x00800000` for smallest normal, `0x7f7fffff` for largest normal, to `0x7f800000` for infinity.

If both operands are negative, the operands in the comparison must be swapped,

`if (__float_as_int(b) <rel-op> __float_as_int(a))`

since the bit patterns are going to range from `0x80000000` for negative zero (-2<sup>32</sup> when interpreted as `int`), over `0x80000001` (-(2<sup>32</sup>-1) when interpreted as `int`) to `0xff800000` for negative infinity (-8388608 when interpreted as `int`).

Since comparisons on `float` are typically at least as fast as comparisons on `int`, there is normally no reason to replace `float` comparisons in this fashion. One situation where it may make sense is if the program is compiled with `-ftz=true` but an isolated comparison with denormal support is needed.

In a similar approach, one can also replace some `double` comparisons with integer comparisons by extracting the most significant 32 bits of the operand with `__double2hiint()` and compare the resulting integers. This approach is mostly applicable to comparisons with simple constants. It has definite performance benefits, and if you have a look at the header file `math_functions_dbl_ptx3.h` in CUDA 6.5 you will find that technique being applied quite extensively.